# Как написать шаблонную строку, если есть теги и тернарное выражение?

Tags: javascript, строки

Вот рабочий пример, но вдруг вздумалось написать покороче и заодно "пощупать" шаблонные строки.

```
somediv.innerHTML = (resp.length == 0)
? `<p><b>Файлов загружено: ${resp.length} </b></p>` 
: `<p><b>Файлов загружено: ${resp.length} </b></p>
<ul id="files"></ul><br>
<button class="padding-5" id="del">Удалить файлы</button>`
```

Нерабочий пример:

```
somediv.innerHTML = `<p><b>Файлов загружено: ${resp.length == 0}
? '0</b></p>'
: ${resp.length}
<ul id="files"></ul><br>
<button class="padding-5" id="del">Удалить файлы</button>`
```

`ul` и `button` появляются только когда файлы есть, то есть, `resp.length != 0`, а фраза "Файлов загружено" есть в любом случае.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы там пробуете использовать `${значение}` одновременно как `(условие) ?` ... потому и не работает) Если скопировать ваш код сюда → https://jsfiddle.net/ , можно убедиться, что он вообще является просто строкой в этом коде, и в принципе не мог бы сработать как код. Или, надо было так: `${ (условие) ? ... : ... }` — весь тернарный внутри `${...}` но в таких случаях краткость не всегда считается крутым. Это может просто лишний раз запутать код)

У строк есть такая фишка, их можно 'клеить' через плюс:

```js
var bu = 'bubu';

console.log( 'строка-1' + ", " + `строка ${bu}-2 — ` + bu )

//(можно добавить и переменную. Уже без кавычек)
/* Т.е. 
`строка ${bu}-1`
 
  то же самое, что и     

'строка ' + bu + '-1'     
*/
```

Поэтому, всё что и так должно отображаться, оставляем как есть, `+` добавляем или пустую строку, или нужный кусок кода - уже в зависимости от условия, так:

```
let x = (resp.length == 0) ? "" : `<ul id="files"></ul><br><button class="padding-5" id="del">Удалить файлы</button>`;

somediv.innerHTML = `<p><b>Файлов загружено: ${resp.length} </b></p>` + x;
```

*Ну можно и без переменной, просто в одну строчку. Но так легче вникать))

Comment: `leftBar.innerHTML = `<p><b>Файлов загружено: ${resp.length}</b></p>` + (resp.length) 
    ? `<ul id="files"></ul><br>
    <button class="padding-5" id="del">Удалить файлы</button>` 
    : '';`

Если написать без переменной, как Вы предложили, пропадает фраза "Файлов загружено". Почему? 

P.S Как в комментарии код показать по-человечески?

Comment: Я почему-то считал, клеить через "+" не очень хорошо, когда есть шаблонные строки - что-то вроде стереотипа "так делали в es5, когда не было шабл. строк"

Comment: Прикольно) Там видимо получается ошибка из-за приоритетов выполнения кода. Если взять весь тернарный в обычные скобки `(...)`, работает. P.s. нуу... в зависимости от длины строчки, которую нужно приклеить) Когда-как удобнее...

Comment: Js любит такие сюрпризы подкидывать, как здесь со скобками... Я, как новичок в js, испытываю смешанные чувства в таких ситуациях: то что, написано в коде раньше, куда-то девается или как-будто совсем не написано. И действительно сразу не скажешь почему... Спасибо за помощь!